# Get a URL from a String

Tags: php, string, url

For a little while now I've been searching for a code to get URL's out of a string using PHP. I'm basically trying to get a Shortened URL out of a message, and then later do a HEAD request to find the actual link.

Anyone have any code that returns URLs from strings?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit for Ghost Dog:**

Here is a sample of what I am parsing:

```
$test = "I am testing this application for http://test.com YAY!";
```

And here is the response I got that solved it:

```
$regex = '$\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]$i';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$A = $result[0];

foreach($A as $B)
{
    $URL = GetRealURL($B);
    echo "$URL<BR>";    
}


function GetRealURL( $url ) 
{ 
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch ); 
    return $header['url']; 
}
```

See Answer for the Details.

Comment: how about show an example of what you are parsing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code may be helpful (see MadTechie's latest post):

http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php/topic,245248.msg1146218.html#msg1146218

> ```
> <?php
> $string = "some random text http://tinyurl.com/9uxdwc some http://google.com random text http://tinyurl.com/787988";
>
> $regex = '$\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]$i';
>
> preg_match_all($regex, $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
> $A = $result[0];
>
> foreach($A as $B)
> {
>    $URL = GetRealURL($B);
>    echo "$URL<BR>";   
> }
>
>
> function GetRealURL( $url ) 
> { 
>    $options = array(
>       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
>       CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
>       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
>       CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
>       CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider",
>       CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
>       CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
>       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
>       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
>    ); 
>
>    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
>    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
>    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
>    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
>    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
>    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
>    curl_close( $ch ); 
>    return $header['url']; 
> }  
>
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

You'll need to tune the regexp to get exactly what you want.

To get the URL out, consider something as simple as:

`curl -I http://url.com/path | grep Location: | awk '{print $2}'`