# get url from string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a URL from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146198/get-a-url-from-a-string)

Hi, im trying to extract a url from a string using regexp. the string is something like:
"lorem ipsum baby www.test.com lorem", "lorem ipsum http://www.test.com foo bar" or "lorem www.test.com" with no trailing whitespace.
using
`MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(adress, @"(www.+|http.+)([\s]|$)");`
returns the entire string. Could any regexp-guru help me out on this one?

Edit:
Solved it this way:
`MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(adress, @"(www[^ \s]+|http[^ \s]+)([\s]|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

adress = mc[0].Value;

WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();

task.URL = adress;

task.Show();`

Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: If you're looking for **VERY** primitive: `((?:https?:\/\/|www|[^\s]+\.[a-z]{2,3})[^\s]*?)[\.\?;:]?` should work. But you'll need a very long regex to eliminate all the meta-characters that could surround urls, or be within them, etc.

Comment: Is this place turning on its head?

Comment: with the number of people that want a regex to match a URL, microsoft should make a standard library of common expressions and put it in the .NET framework somewhere. I think it would be cool to just do `Url.Matches(address)` or `Guid.Matches(@string)` or `DateTime.Matches(@string)`

Comment: @Kelloti: 2nded. Go hit up MS connect and bring back a link ;p

Comment: ok, please give this one lots of attention: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646841/add-common-regular-expressions-to-net-framework-5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we are missing the obvious here that there is actually nothing wrong with this code.

Perhaps the OP is not calling the match.value correctly.

```
string adress = "hello www.google.ca";
// Size the control to fill the form with a margin
MatchCollection ms = Regex.Matches(adress, @"(www.+|http.+)([\s]|$)");
string testMatch = ms[0].Value.ToString();
```

testMatch only contains "www.google.ca"

Isn't this your intention newa?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. :| Thanks :)

Comment: Does not work with the below string `***Free shipping applies to all 90-day supplies and orders over $49 being shipped to the US, Canada and Mexico. Certain shipping exclusions may apply. Visit our <a href="https://shop.mercola.com/pages/help?utm_source=dnl&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_content=policy&amp;utm_campaign=yyyymmddZ1" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #666666 !important; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:normal; text-align: left; line-height: 14px; font-size: 11px;" target="_blank">shipping policy</a> page for more details. While supplies last.`

Comment: @PB-BitWiser The answer was to address the OP incorrect usage of testing the match collection. I'm not much of a regex guy myself.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
string txt = "lorem ipsum baby http:\\\\www.google.com\/";
Regex regx = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection ms = regx.Matches(txt);
```

Comment: Author wanted to match "www" prefix, not only those that started with http. ;p Either way, I think [RegExLib](http://regexlib.com/) is as good a place to start as any.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the "." identifier matches anything, including those trailing spaces you want to end the capture at. If you change the ".+" to "[^ ]+", or make the first capture "nongreedy" by putting a "?:" just inside the opening parenthesis, you should get the answer you want.