# How to filter a string

Tags: php, string

I have this string:

```
"small:
http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/player_boxshot.jpg
boxshot:
http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/boxshot.jpg"
```

I want to get only the first image link (after the word "small") and ignore all the rest (the word "boxshot" and the link after it).

How can I make it?

Comment: and what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a URL from a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146198/get-a-url-from-a-string)

Comment: In this case will 'boxshot' always be there after the first image link? If it is don't use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way:

```
<?php
    $str='small: http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/player_boxshot.jpg boxshot: http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/boxshot.jpg';
    $parts=explode('boxshot:',$str);
    $small=$parts[0];
    echo($small);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use it and like my ans. `string` is your above whole string

```
substr(string,0,stripos(string,"boxshot")-1);
```

Comment: This is how I'd do this except don't start at 0, presuming `small:` doesn't change, you want to start at 6.

Comment: Stop saying **Like my Answer.. Like my answer..** This is not Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "small:
http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/player_boxshot.jpg
boxshot:
http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/boxshot.jpg";

preg_match_all('~http(.*?)jpg~i',trim($string),$matches);
var_dump($matches[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = "small:
http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/player_boxshot.jpg
boxshot:
http://img.exent.com/free/frg/products/666550/boxshot.jpg";

// replace all 2 or more consecutive spaces with 1 space
$string = preg_replace( '/\s\s+/i', ' ', $string);
$array = explode( ' ', $string);
echo $array[1];
```

Hope this helps.