# PHP Replace Dynamic url from string

Tags: php, string, url, replace

I have a robot voice that turns sentences into spoken mp3 files.
But the robot voice can't pronounce urls so I want to filter the urls out.

I got dynamic strings coming in that can look like this:
"Hello my name is Jeffrey"
This works fine but strings can also contains urls and looks like this:
"Hello http://wwww.google.nl is a very nice site."
or
"Hello how are you doing https://soundcloud.com/theforeignexchangemusic/zo-manmade-sampler …"
or
"Take a look at this picture http://instagram.com/p/xPiSn8Pmli/ "
And so on

If a string contains an url I want to replace the url with a word.
Does anybody know a good way of doing this?
Because the strings are dynamic (Length, content and location) I find it very hard to do.
If someone has a good idea please let me know!
Would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: You can use a regular expression that searches for URLs and using said regular expression, replace the URL with a word of your choice.

Comment: Well, I still understand your question properly. So, if it is coming like "Hello http://wwww.google.nl is a very nice site." then you want it to be like this "Hello Google is a very nice site."?

Comment: Yes or even "Hello a website is a very nice site."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use RegEx to parse the strings to see if URLs come up.

Using RegEx to then find the base domain and then vocalize that.

[/^(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?$/ Regex for URLs](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)

[For more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146198/get-a-url-from-a-string)

[For Parsing your URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is looking for exactly the same thing here is a working example.

```
<?php
$hallo = 'Hey it works. http://onderbroekenlol.nl something behind the url.';
$str = preg_replace("/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\w]+\.)([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?/", "a website", $hallo);
print $str;
?>
```

Comment: `[\w]` is more simply written as `\w`. Inside of a character class, `.` does not need to be escaped.  If you have a pattern with `/` in it, it is simpler to use a unique character as the pattern delimiter such as `~` so that you don't have to escape all of the `/` characters.